# What manages dual sim phones

Tags: dual-sim

So about dual sim phones, what manages their work is that app, or kernel support, or maybe ROM support (support has to be built into rom). Or some combination of all mentioned?

Comment: Certainly at least on ROM level - if ROM doesn't have dual SIM management UI and libs, you won't even see the 2nd SIM and the phone will appear single-SIM. This is obvious for some devices that have both single-SIM and dual-SIM variants and have a flashable ROM for the single-SIM variant.

Comment: @AndyYan In that case how could I build ROM for dual sim (theoretical question don't mark question as off topic), because I don't know any rom that supports that.?

Comment: I don't really know about that... I ain't a dev either :/ Better wait for a complete, backed-up answer to show up.

Comment: There is no such thing as ROM support. A rom is just a collection of partitions. The kernel needs to be aware of the hardware, and be able to talk to the modem. The manufacturer should provide the device source that handles this.

Comment: @jiggunjer yes, but there has to be some app with UI so you can 'switch' or turn off sim card. I tought it was a ROM support because when you use custom in most cases you lose dual sim support. Manufacturer should provide source for kernel or for that particular software which manages cards?

Comment: There doesn't have to be any UI, but in many cases the settings app offers access to the SIM management. It may use a vendor app under the hood. Such apps should be part of the device tree, but might not be open source.

Comment: @jiggunjer Hm, so, what for i'm looking for, .apk file, .so file or something else?

Comment: an apk, if it exists. I don't know the technical details of SIM cards, but there might be special protocols involved. The app may also depend on a specific kernel version that supports your RIL. In other words there could be many dependencies and requirements for such an app to work on your phone.

Comment: @jiggunjer only .apk that I could find that maybe suits description is "Dual sim status" but it seems like it only provides widgets, apk is ~500kb..